# When I step over the button it turns gray extjs

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

```
new Ext.Button({
   
    text: '<div style="color: white">INFORMA</div>'
    ,style: {
       'background-color': '#0099ff',
       'border-radius': '5px',
       'padding-left': '5px',
       'padding-right': '5px',
       'padding-top': '1px',
       'padding-bottom': '1px'
   }
    ,handler : function() {
        .....
        ...
    }
})
```

The problem I have is, when I put the mouse over the button it turns gray, and I would like it to remain the same color as it was before, blue. How could I fix it?

Before the mouse gets on top:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsPI1.png)

When mouse gets on top:

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWSx0.png)

Comment: I am not sure why that is doing what it is doing but you can change colors (hover, focus, select) with a custom "ui".   Also if you can put this in a fiddle it would make it easy for someone to help you.  What version and of EXTJS are you using and what tool kit (classic or modern)?

Comment: This is only one button .  I'm using classic extjs (3.4.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following override will remove the mouseover color:

```
Ext.define('Override.Button', {
    override: 'Ext.Button',
    onMouseOver: function (e) {
        if (!this.disabled) {
            var internal = e.within(this.el, true);
            if (!internal) {
                //this.el.addClass('x-btn-over');
                if (!this.monitoringMouseOver) {
                    this.doc.on('mouseover', this.monitorMouseOver, this);
                    this.monitoringMouseOver = true;
                }
                this.fireEvent('mouseover', this, e);
            }
            if (this.isMenuTriggerOver(e, internal)) {
                this.fireEvent('menutriggerover', this, this.menu, e);
            }
        }
    },

    // private
    onMouseOut: function (e) {
        var internal = e.within(this.el) && e.target != this.el.dom;
        //this.el.removeClass('x-btn-over');
        this.fireEvent('mouseout', this, e);
        if (this.isMenuTriggerOut(e, internal)) {
            this.fireEvent('menutriggerout', this, this.menu, e);
        }
    }
});

new Ext.Button({
    text: '<div style="color: white">INFORMA</div>',
    style: {
        'background-color': '#0099ff',
        'border-radius': '5px',
        'padding-left': '5px',
        'padding-right': '5px',
        'padding-top': '1px',
        'padding-bottom': '1px'
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function () {}
})
```

Or you can [generate your own theme](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.x/guides/concepts/ThemeBuilder.html) to change the '.x-btn-over' CSS class.

Comment: May you tell me the extjs version and toolkit you are using?

Comment: I'm using extjs 3.4.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but Extjs 3.4 doesn´t have an Ext.define

Comment: I did it an answer , keep an eye , thank you

Comment: Do you know if for example i have var button1 = new Ext.Button.. , how can override only that button and not all buttons?

Comment: Extend the class and override there appropriate methods.

Comment: How do you suggest it? (Sorry im not extjs expert)

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/extjs/example/19284/extend-vs-override

Comment: Thank you , but i edited my answer i saw an easier way to do , using handleMouseEvents

Answer (score 1):

That's how i solved because Ext.define doesn't works, thanks to the code of @Arthus Rubens:

```
Ext.override(Ext.Button,{
    onMouseOver: function (e) {
        if (!this.disabled) {
            var internal = e.within(this.el, true);
            if (!internal) {
                if (!this.monitoringMouseOver) {
                    this.doc.on('mouseover', this.monitorMouseOver, this);
                    this.monitoringMouseOver = true;
                }
                this.fireEvent('mouseover', this, e);
            }
            if (this.isMenuTriggerOver(e, internal)) {
                this.fireEvent('menutriggerover', this, this.menu, e);
            }
        }
    },

    onMouseOut: function (e) {
        var internal = e.within(this.el) && e.target != this.el.dom;
        this.fireEvent('mouseout', this, e);
        if (this.isMenuTriggerOut(e, internal)) {
            this.fireEvent('menutriggerout', this, this.menu, e);
        }
    }
});
```

Second way of do it calling handleMouseEvents:false

```
new Ext.Button({
    text: '<div style="color: white">INFORMA</div>',
    handleMouseEvents:false
    ,style: {
        'background-color': '#0099ff',
        'border-radius': '5px',
        'padding-left': '5px',
        'padding-right': '5px',
        'padding-top': '1px',
        'padding-bottom': '1px'
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function () {}
})
```